# General questions about iOS apps updating

Tags: ios, image, file, app-store, updates

I've already asked here for guidence regarding `sqlite` database modifications when updating an iOS app submitted to the App Store, but, what about resources in `Supporting Files` project's directory? What if, for instance, tomorrow I change the app's look & feel and I need to remove some of the `png` image files I had, or change their name?

In general, how should app's changes be managed when submitting an app's update? Is there any Apple's documentation regarding this? I couldn't find it.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** When you download an app update from the App Store and it is installed, is `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method called? Is it there where you should manage any files you need to remove or modify, or should it be handled in another method?

Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an app is 'updated', the `Documents` and `Library/Preferences` directory is maintained by the system, and the app is deleted. The new version is installed, the `Documents` directory is returned. It is up to you to ensure that any data changes are supported between versions, e.g. Core Data model mapping, any user data, etc.

In terms of changing image names, or removing files. Providing you update all code references accordingly, this is fine. The app itself is deleted. Just the `Documents` directory and `Library/Preferences` is guaranteed to be backed up.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Another question comes to me: where should you manage the files you need to remove or modify when installing an update? In the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method? What methods are called when an app update from the Store is installed?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, like I said, when an 'update' occurs, it will maintain your Documents and Preferences directories, delete the rest, and install the new version of the app and load the existing data.

Comment: My fault, I didn't explain properly. I'm talking about deleting manually certain files that, as you said, would be kept in `Documents` and are no longer needed, and copying new ones. Is there a way to know in code when an update has been installed?

Comment: Store the current app version in your NSUserDefaults when the app launches for the first time (e.g., check the value in NSUserDefaults is nil, if it is, this is a first load, so store the current number), on every subsequent launch you can perform a comparison of the current version with the stored version, if it is different, you have just upgraded. Obviously this is not foolproof as the NSUserDefaults can be modified by the user with a file navigator.

Comment: I see... which method should perform that? Is `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` called when app is updated? Or it should be done in another method?

Comment: That's a fine place to do it. Just check if a value for your key exists, if it is nil, this is likely a first install, so set your current version to the NSUserDefaults. If it isn't nil, compare the value to your current version and act accordingly

Comment: Thanks! So... can I assume that `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` will be always called when the app is updated?

Comment: application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: is called every time the app launches. If the user has updated the app, this means it was killed, so yes, the next time it loads this method will get called.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you question correctly, but I believe if you update your app and have to remove some of the images in Supporting Files, you would need to update other places where those images where used (Storyboards, source files), or the new version of you app would break.

Taking this into account I believe removing images shouldn't be a problem as long as you update the rest of your app in a way that they are not referenced any more. Old versions of your app will still have the images available until they are updated, and when they get updated they won't need them any more.

Hope this helps.